# How to break a loop that trigger from an inner promise function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

How to break a sequelize promise .then({}). i want to break the exit to the then promise and break the loop. when if condition triggered. the code is same as the following. not my exact code.

```
int i = 0;
   while(i<result.length){

      db.Model.findAll({
      where:{
         x : X,
         w : W,
         z : z
      }).then(result => {
        if(result[i].x == null || result[i].x == undefined){
             // update and break here!
             update(): // something like that
             // how i break the outer loop.
        }
        if(result[i].w > 0){
             // how i break the outer loop.
        }
        if(result[i].z < 100){
             // how i break the outer loop.
        }
   })
 i++;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't fully understand what's going on here, but why doesn't a simple `break` expression work? Maybe something like `result.some()` and then return true when you want to break could work better.

Comment: Look for cancel tokens or you can use bluebird

Comment: im so sorry, i have a wrong sample code for thak you. e updated the sample hope you can get it now.  thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. `result` is undefined.

Comment: 2 issues.. 1) What is the point of performing the same db query over and over..? 2) You have to move your `while` loop inside the `then` stage and return something meaningful for the next `then` stage.

Comment: thats not my exact code..  this just a piece of code of my real code.. my point is the problem i want to solve in this kind of scenario.. this is the problem i'm facing now.. Thank you

Comment: Instead of looping, recurse.

Comment: i solve this using recursive..

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `async / await` and implement it like this :

```
async function your_function(){
    // init your result varibale
    for(let i=0 ; i < result.length ; i++) {
        let mresult = await db.Model.findAll({
                                            where:{
                                                x : X,
                                                w : W,
                                                z : z
                                            })
        if(mresult[i].x == null || mresult[i].x == undefined){
             update(): // something like that
             break; // <------------- Break it like this
        }
        if(mresult[i].w > 0){
             break; // <------------- Break it like this
        }
        if(mresult[i].z < 100){
             break; // <------------- Break it like this
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: debugging nowww.. :)

Comment: await is a reserved word

Comment: check your node version ? it should be 7/8+

Comment: Then check the syntax for async/await , flow is 100% right , There should be something with syntax , please check that.